# Solving an equation using 'replacement'

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have this equation:  $$ a \cdot 2^a = b$$  and need to find solutions for $a$.

And I know it's complicated and has to do something with the $W$ function.

But I've come up with a way which does not work for some-reason... and I would like you to have a look and help me find the mistake!

We can write any number $a = 2^k$ where $k$ isn't necessarily in $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$
so we have: $2^k \cdot 2^{2^k} = b$ which gives: $2^{2^k +1} =b $ and thus: $2^k + 1 = \log_2{b}$

And we get that $k = \log_2(\log_2b -1)$  and thus $a = 2^k = 2^{\log_2(\log_2b -1)} = \log_2b -1$

However this does not work! Why? Here is an example:
$a \cdot 2^a = 24$  In my example $a = \log_2(24) -1 \approx 3.58$ but it is actually $3$ ...

Edit: I am so dumb.. it should be $2^{2^k + k}$ ... Is there a way to solve this kind of equation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^k \cdot 2^{2^k} = 2^{k + 2^k}$, not $2^{1+2^k}$.

EDIT: The solutions of $a 2^a = b$ are $$a = \frac{W(b \ln(2))}{\ln(2)}$$
where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.  If you want real solutions:
there is none if $b < -1/(e \ln(2))$.  If $b = -1/(e \ln(2))$, the only real solution is $-1/\ln(2)$.  If $-1/(e \ln(2)) < b < 0$, there are two real solutions,
one with the "$-1$" branch and one with the principal branch of $W$.  If $b \ge 0$, the only real solution is with the principal branch.

Comment: I've spotted the mistake as soon as I posted it... I am so tired haha... is there a way to solve it? more explicitly where $b = 24$ ? I mean, only $a=3$ makes sense.. but is it the only solution? why?

Comment: Thank you sir. But how did the Lambert came into play? We should use it only if we have the form $x \cdot e^x$ but here we have $x 2^x$

Comment: @StackOMeow $a2^a = b \Rightarrow ae^{\ln(2^a)} =b\Rightarrow ae^{a\ln(2)}=b \Rightarrow a\ln(2) e^{a\ln(2)}=b\ln(2)$ 

on the left side we now have the form $xe^x$ where $x=a\ln(2)$ therefore, we have
$a \ln(2)=W(b\ln(2))\Rightarrow a=\frac{W(b\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}$